# How, if a var exists, create an object or discard the object in the query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with mongodb, with a ajax form, it works fine... i want to discard some elements in the query. this is the code:

```
var preVariable=
    {
        precio_alquiler: {$lte:query.price_input_by_user},
        tipo_usuario: query.type_of_user,
    };

db.collection('data').find(preVariable,{_id:0},{safe:true}, function(err, result)
```

Explanation:

precio_alquiler is the price of the element

tipo_usuario is a select in the form that contains

```
select(name='type_of_user')
                        option(value="Commerce") Comercio
                        option(value="User") Usuario
                        option(value="Mayorist") Mayor
```

So the question is... if the user want to consult the price of an element and ignore the type of the user, how to create the query variable???
Here's an example that can explain the question

```
var preVariable=
    {
        precio_alquiler: {$lte:query.price_input_by_user},
        tipo_usuario: query.type_of_user || "dont create the object tipo_usuario",
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to initialize the object with known properties at first, and conditionally add those that are depending on input:

```
var preVariable = {
    precio_alquiler: { $lte: query.price_input_by_user }
};

if(query.type_of_user) {
    preVariable.tipo_usuario = query.type_of_user;
}
```

Comment: im trying to avoid conditionals because is not one object there are many

Comment: Then surely you have a list of all the possible property names?

Answer (score 1):

You could create different object:

```
var preVariable = query.type_of_user ? {
    precio_alquiler: {
        $lte: query.price_input_by_user
    },
    tipo_usuario: query.type_of_user
} : {
    precio_alquiler: {
        $lte: query.price_input_by_user
    }
};
```

Comment: i dont understand exactly, that is a conditional like var foo=1==1?'one':'other else';

Comment: Eeeek! I like the ternary operator, but that's too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these fields, then this may be better than using conditionals:

```
var preVariable = {
    precio_alquiler: {$lte:query.price_input_by_user},
    tipo_usuario: query.type_of_user,
    //... more
};
// Remove the undefined fields
for (var prop in preVariable) {
    if (preVariable[prop] === undefined) delete preVariable[prop];
}
```